# Django-recaptcha always showing "This field is required." even-tough it is there

Tags: python, django, recaptcha, django-recaptcha

I am trying to use Recaptcha v3 in one of my projects. Unfortunately the form.valid_date() method fails all the time with "This field is required.".

Running django-recaptcha.

forms.py looks like this:

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # adding some default validators
    phone = forms.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)], error_messages={'invalid':_("Please add a valid phone number.")})
    terms = forms.BooleanField()

    captcha = ReCaptchaField(
        public_key=settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY,
        private_key=settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,
        widget=ReCaptchaV3(
            attrs={
                'required_score': 0.85,
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['phone', 'terms']

    def clean_phone(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        if not validate_phone(data):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please add a valid phone number. "))
        return data

    def clean_terms(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['terms']
        if not True:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please accept the T&Cs"))
        return data
```

views.py looks like this:

```
def register_web(request: object) -> object:

    key = request.GET.get('key', '')
    merchant = request.GET.get('merchant', '')

    if request.method == 'POST':

        print(form.is_valid())
        print(form.errors)

        if form.is_valid():

            phone = phone_filter(str(request.POST.get('phone')).replace(' ', ''))
            name = request.POST.get('name', '')

            confirmationForm = ConfirmationForm()
            return render(request, 'registerWebConfirmation.html', {'context':context })

        else:
            
            return render(request, 'registerWeb.html', {'form': form})

    else:

        return render(request, 'registerWeb.html', {'form': form})
```

The print in the views.py states:

```
False
<ul class="errorlist"><li>captcha<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

The template looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.phone.errors }}
                            {% render_field form.phone placeholder=form.phone.label class+="form-control" %}


                            {% if form.name %}
                            <br /><br />{% render_field form.name placeholder=form.name.label class+="form-control" %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="advanced" value="1" />
                            {% endif %}

                            <br /><br />
                            {{ form.captcha }}
                            <input type="hidden" name="merchant" value="{{ merchant }}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ key }}"/>

                            <div class="d-flex cb-container">
                                {{ form.terms.errors }}
                                {% render_field form.terms placeholder=form.terms.label %}
                                <label for="id_terms">Accept <a href="/dataprivacy">T&Cs</a></label>
                            </div>

                            <input class="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="{% trans "Anmelden" %}">

                        </form>
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: can you put the details of function `valid_date()` which is failing ?

Comment: Not sure I do understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to replicate your problem and as you said the form's `is_valid()` always returns `False` with the error that `This field is required.`

But after I signed up for a [ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) and change the `RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY` and `RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY` to proper values, the error disappeared and the `form.is_vaild()` returns `True`.

I assume you're not using real values for these configs and changing that fixes your problem.
Or maybe you do put the real values but you're still getting the error. Then I suggest double checking the values. There must be a typo.

Comment: You are right, I unfortunately mixed up private and public key which resultated in this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @David You're welcome. I'd appreciate it if you award the bounty and vote up the answer as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Done. Sorry, my first bug bounty. Thought accepting the answer is enough.